# change the gantt chart x axis to seconds with 5sec intervals - jFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to change the x axis values of this charts to seconds with 5sec intervals. Here the common x axis in hours. i want to change it to seconds. i want to user this chart to a different scenario. i have tried the "new Second()" object but confused. can anybody help me with this.

```
public class XYTaskDatasetDemo2 extends ApplicationFrame {

/**
 * Constructs the demo application.
 *
 * @param title  the frame title.
 */
public XYTaskDatasetDemo2(String title) {
    super(title);
    JPanel chartPanel = createDemoPanel();
  //        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 300));
    setContentPane(chartPanel);
}

/**
 * Creates a subplot.
 *
 * @param dataset  the dataset.
 *
 * @return A subplot.
 */
private static XYPlot createSubplot1(XYDataset dataset) {
    XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer = new XYLineAndShapeRenderer();
    renderer.setUseFillPaint(true);
    renderer.setBaseFillPaint(Color.white);
    renderer.setBaseShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(-4.0, -4.0, 8.0, 8.0));
    renderer.setAutoPopulateSeriesShape(false);
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("Y");
    yAxis.setLowerMargin(0.1);
    yAxis.setUpperMargin(0.1);
    XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, new DateAxis("Time"), yAxis,
            renderer);
    return plot;
}

/**
 * Creates a subplot.
 *
 * @param dataset  the dataset.
 *
 * @return A subplot.
 */
private static XYPlot createSubplot2(IntervalXYDataset dataset) {
    DateAxis xAxis = new DateAxis("Date/Time");
    SymbolAxis yAxis = new SymbolAxis("Resources", new String[] {"Team A",
            "Team B", "Team C", "Team D", "Team E"});
    yAxis.setGridBandsVisible(false);
    XYBarRenderer renderer = new XYBarRenderer();
    renderer.setUseYInterval(true);
    XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, xAxis, yAxis, renderer);
    return plot;
}

/**
 * Creates a demo chart.
 *
 * @return A demo chart.
 */
private static JFreeChart createChart() {
    CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(
            new DateAxis("Date/Time"));
    plot.setDomainPannable(true);
    plot.add(createSubplot1(createDataset1()));
    plot.add(createSubplot2(createDataset2()));
    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("XYTaskDatasetDemo2", plot);
    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);
    return chart;
}

/**
 * Creates a panel for the demo.
 *
 * @return A panel.
 */
public static JPanel createDemoPanel() {
    return new ChartPanel(createChart());
}

/**
 * Creates a dataset for the demo.  Normally a dataset wouldn't be hard
 * coded like this - it would be read from a file or a database or some
 * other source.
 *
 * @return A dataset.
 */
private static XYDataset createDataset1() {
    TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
    TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Time Series 1");
    s1.add(new Hour(0, new Day()), 20214.5);
    s1.add(new Hour(4, new Day()), 73346.5);
    s1.add(new Hour(8, new Day()), 54643.6);
    s1.add(new Hour(12, new Day()), 92683.8);
    s1.add(new Hour(16, new Day()), 110235.4);
    s1.add(new Hour(20, new Day()), 120742.5);
    s1.add(new Hour(24, new Day()), 90654.5);
    dataset.addSeries(s1);
    return dataset;
}

/**
 * Creates a dataset for the demo.  Normally a dataset wouldn't be hard
 * coded like this - it would be read from a file or a database or some
 * other source.
 *
 * @return A dataset.
 */
private static IntervalXYDataset createDataset2() {
    XYTaskDataset dataset = new XYTaskDataset(createTasks());
    dataset.setTransposed(true);
    dataset.setSeriesWidth(0.6);
    return dataset;
}

/**
 * Creates a task series collection.
 *
 * @return A task series collection.
 */
private static TaskSeriesCollection createTasks() {
    TaskSeriesCollection dataset = new TaskSeriesCollection();
    TaskSeries s1 = new TaskSeries("Team A");
    s1.add(new Task("T1a", new Hour(11, new Day())));
    s1.add(new Task("T1b", new Hour(14, new Day())));
    s1.add(new Task("T1c", new Hour(16, new Day())));
    TaskSeries s2 = new TaskSeries("Team B");
    s2.add(new Task("T2a", new Hour(13, new Day())));
    s2.add(new Task("T2b", new Hour(19, new Day())));
    s2.add(new Task("T2c", new Hour(21, new Day())));
    TaskSeries s3 = new TaskSeries("Team C");
    s3.add(new Task("T3a", new Hour(13, new Day())));
    s3.add(new Task("T3b", new Hour(19, new Day())));
    s3.add(new Task("T3c", new Hour(21, new Day())));
    TaskSeries s4 = new TaskSeries("Team D");
    s4.add(new Task("T4a", new Day()));
    TaskSeries s5 = new TaskSeries("Team E");
    s5.add(new Task("T5a", new Day()));
    dataset.add(s1);
    dataset.add(s2);
    dataset.add(s3);
    dataset.add(s4);
    dataset.add(s5);
    return dataset;
}

/**
 * Starting point for the demonstration application.
 *
 * @param args  ignored.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XYTaskDatasetDemo2 demo = new XYTaskDatasetDemo2(
            "JFreeChart : XYTaskDatasetDemo2.java");
    demo.pack();
    RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
    demo.setVisible(true);
}

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the horizontal Axis by changing the createChart method this way :

```
private static JFreeChart createChart() {
    CombinedDomainXYPlot plot = new CombinedDomainXYPlot(new DateAxis("Date/Time"));
    plot.setDomainPannable(true);
    plot.add(createSubplot1(createDataset1()));
    plot.add(createSubplot2(createDataset2()));

    // Get the horizontal Axis for the plot
    DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
    // Change the unit tick to 5 hours
    axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.HOUR, 5));
    // Change the date format used to display tick values
    axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm"));

    JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart("XYTaskDatasetDemo2", plot);

    chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
    ChartUtilities.applyCurrentTheme(chart);
    return chart;
}
```

In this example, I define a 5 hour tick on the horizontal Axis, as it fits your sample data.
If you want a 5 sec interval, use :

```
   axis.setTickUnit(new DateTickUnit(DateTickUnitType.SECOND, 5));
```